# Stripe form submission creates payment token but doesn't redirect despite successful token creation

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I'm currently working on integrating Stripe payments into my web application. I've set up the form submission to create a payment token upon clicking the Stripe payment button. However, after successful token creation, the form doesn't redirect as expected.

I've tried retrieving the complete form values upon clicking the payment button using JavaScript, and the payment token is indeed created. However, the redirection doesn't occur. I'm uncertain whether the issue lies in my form submission or in Stripe's configuration.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<form action="become-a-partner.php?action=stripe_payment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-body">

    <hr>
    <div class="row p-t-20">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Restaurant Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="res_name" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      // This is Stripe code where the payment dialog box opens for payment 
      // After payment done it dose not redirect
      <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-key="<?php echo $publishableKey?>" data-amount="<?php echo 10000 ?>" data-name="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?> " data-description="Membership Payment" data-image="images/img/logo_web.jpg"
        data-currency="usd" data-email="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?>">
      </script>
</form>
```

Thank You and looking forward for solution

Comment: Which doc did you follow for this Stripe integration? This doesn't look like any recommended official Stripe's integration.